# Simplifiying an equation

Tags: limits, summation

The equation I have is this:
My question is, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} {1 \over n}$ = 0, won't this whole expression be equal to 0?

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$ ${1 \over n}\sum_{k=1}^n \arcsin({k \over n})$

Comment: By the way, use **\arcsin** to generate $\arcsin$ which is more legible than $arcsin$.

Comment: ok. thanks, first time I've used the formatting

Comment: What about $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}n$?

Comment: oh, ok I see. thanks @ArnaudMortier

Comment: No problem :) Most people who just start out on the MSE skip the LATEX tutorials and then get frustrated because nobody can properly answer their question. fortunately, you are not one of them :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: This is a Riemann sum, so your limit can be expressed as a definite integral.

Comment: The integral I got is $\int_{0}^1 \arcsin(x)$ is this correct? @StubbornAtom and then I get $ {1 \over n}  * {pi \over 2} $

Comment: Yes the integral is $\int_0^1 \arcsin (x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ which equals $\pi/2 -1$. An integration by parts would work I think.

Comment: how come is it $ {pi \over 2} -1$?, isn't arcsin(0) = 0

Comment: @StubbornAtom forgot to tag you in my question above

Comment: What is the indefinite integral you get? Or what do you get as the definite integral?

Comment: Why is the indefinite integral you get pi / 2 - 1, as you wrote up there @StubbornAtom , where did the -1 come from?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arcsin(x)+from+0+to+1. Check the indefinite integral.

Comment: thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the first factor tends to zero, but you must also consider that the second factor may grow fast enough to "outdo" that.

If the second factor is bounded as $n\to\infty$, your conclusion is correct. Otherwise, you must try to analyze the growth rate of the second factor.